# Can't repair data source, QGIS refuses to load .csv file from new location

Tags: qgis

Weeks ago I added several point geometry vector layers onto a QGIS project. The data source for each layer was a simple several-column .csv file with only the first two columns being X-Y coordinates. QGIS displayed them correctly.

Today I moved the .csv files to a new directory on my disk and QGIS promptly couldn't find them and showed a question mark in a triangle next to the layer names.

I was able to "repair" (i.e. repoint to the new location) all other similar point layers, except this one layer with the correct (new path) file shown as its data source in the layer properties refuses to load the points.

I checked file contents, name and path several times, everything seems to be correct. I don't know why QGIS cannot load the points and keeps showing me an empty layer.

QGIS version 3.26.2-Buenos Aires on Windows 10 Home

Comment: Have you tried removing the layer, re-adding the csv, and displaying the XY points again?

Comment: I tried adding a layer from the same .csv file without removing the old layer. QGIS created the new layer with the same name as the old layer. But the point of my question is not to find a workaround but to understand why QGIS refuses to "repair" the data source of an existing layer when it performed the same repair on adjacent layers with the exact same structure, whose only difference from the problem layer is the different coordinates of the points.

Comment: Is tha attribute table empty as well? Or justno geometries?

Comment: The attribute table is empty

Comment: You might want to look at QGIS issues on GitHub, there seem to be reported issues with repaired .CSV files since 3.22

Comment: A few points that maybe could help to understand better what happened: 1) If you move the csv back to the old location, then everything is fine again? 2) When you save/export the csv from QGIS to the new location, does that work? 3) How did you "repair" the data source? 4) Do you have permissions (write/read) in the new folder, where you moved the csv to? And finally: 5) can you share the csv?

Comment: Replying to Babel:
(1) I can't remember where the old location is because I changed my directory structure and the source shown in the layer properties is the new one
(2) I haven't tried saving the layer as a .csv because I assumed it will be empty as the attributes table is totally empty
(3) by right-clicking on the layer I get this option to "repair data source" in the pop-up menu which is in the place in the menu where normally one sees the "change data source"  option

Comment: Babel reply continued:

(4) I looked at the permissions - the permissions to the directories where similar files sit for the layers for which the "repair data source" function worked, do not differ from the directory and layer for which it does not work
(5) yes, I can share the .csv but I am not sure how to do it... there does not seem to be a way to attach files to messages in this thread...

Comment: Replying to Kasper:

Thank you, will check it out

Comment: As I mentioned in the first post, adding a new layer by using the same .csv file in the same new location, does create a second layer with the same name (I am letting my layers generate their names automatically from the file name) and that new layer is fully functional. So the problem does not seem to rest with the file. It looks like some damage has occurred in the internal structure of the "bad" layer. Also, when I try to save the project after I have failed to repair that layer, QGIS crashes

Comment: Also, a small clarification: the layers for whom the "repair" worked, each points to a different directory for its data source (i.e. I moved each csv file from its old directory to a new directory; the new directory is not common but distinct for each .csv data source). The "bad" layer simply points to one such distinct directory which doesn't differ in any way from the other directories of the other "repaired" data sources.